# How do I query JIRA to find issue attributes at a specified date?

Tags: jira, jql

I have to export reports listing some attributes of JIRA issues at a specified date.
So my query would be:

```
project = "XXX" AND fixVersion was "10.14.0.0" ON '2016-12-12 11:00'
```

And the result set would provide the status (mandatory) and other attributes (such as assignee) at the specified date.

For the moment, the result set provides me with the status at the current date, and not at the specified date.

How can I achieve that?

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible by default: JIRA always returns current/most recent values of the fields.

Though, there are workarounds:

1. You can programmatically run JQL query, expanding `changelog` items. Analyzing each change, you can find out value of interested field for the given date. Here is an [example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Is-it-possible-to-get-the-issue-history-using-the-REST-API/qaq-p/510094).
2. If you know some schedule of your reports (e.g. each Monday), you can configure cron job and periodically export issues for later processing.

Here are some related questions in Atlassian community:

- [How do I get a snapshot of issues on a particular day using JQL (rest)?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-Core-questions/How-do-I-get-a-snapshot-of-issues-on-a-particular-day-using-JQL/qaq-p/81738)
- [Snapshot of jira issues statuses on the specific date](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/Snapshot-of-jira-issues-statuses-on-the-specific-date/qaq-p/224476)
- [eazyBI - Snapshot of JIRA issues statuses on the specific dates](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-Core-questions/eazyBI-Snapshot-of-JIRA-issues-statuses-on-the-specific-dates/qaq-p/71829)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very relevant and complete answer!
I tested the result set and indeed there was no way to get attribute values at a given date.
The expand='changelog' solution is very nice, I have now to check out whether we can programmaticaly access our JIRA server or not, depending on network policy.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you! :)